# Area Under Precision-Recall and Area Under ROC curve for different amount of observations

Tags: machine-learning, roc, precision-recall

I am doing a research and thus comparing some algorithms for binary classification. Worth to mention that, the data set is highly imbalanced i.e., the minority class is only 0.2%.

Notation:

Area Under Precision-Recall (AUPRC)

Area Under ROC (AUROC)

My question is, or what I want to have explained; In a scenario I have two classifiers. For the first classifier, call it A, the AUROC and AUPRC is calculated based on 142000 observations where there are 223 observations that is True Positive. For this classifier, A, I obtain AUPRC 0.10 and AUROC 0.95. However, for the second classifier, call it B, based on 1500 observations, where there are 118 True positives among these, I obtain AUPRC of 0.12 and AUROC of 0.60.

Moreover, since the AURPC is more valuable for me, classifier B, is better. However, how can the result from the AUROC of 0.95 vs 0.60 be explained? Has it something to do with the amount of observations that the two classifiers are tested on?

I would appreciate if someone could make an explanation of this.

Thank you.

Comment: The sample sizes are very different so that may account for the difference, especially since you said the minority class is proportionally small. However even so, I don't think there is not enough detail on the specific problem to provide an answer.

Comment: The AUPRC and AUROC for classifier B is computed for a sample size (test set) of 1500 observations. In contrary, AUPRC and AUROC for classifier A is computed for a sample size (test set) of 142000 observations. The test set of 1500 observations contains 118 positives. The test set of  142000 observation contains 223 positives. The AUPRC for classifier A is 0.10 and AUPRC for classifier B is 0.12 i.e., they are quiet similar. However, the AUROC for classifier A is 0.95 and classifier B 0.60. We know that ROC/AUROC is not really good for skewed data sheets. Could this help to explain for me?